# zend framework 2 cron action

Tags: cron, zend-framework2

How do we use a normal Zend Framework 2 controller action (callable from browser) as a cron job? I tried to set one as a cron job but it did not get called.

Do we need a Rest(ful) controller/module for that?

Comment: Maybe you could use a console route?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you are trying to do? In general, I bootstrap a CLI Script and have it call business logic w/out calling a controller. Buy you can always wget your URL if you are simply looking to kick off a process.

Answer (score 2):

Read this: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.console.introduction.html

This explains console routes in a great deal and walks through the process of setting one up.

I used it just last week and it proved very helpful. Console routes can be set up so they are restricted from access via the web.

You could then set up a cron job to just run:

`php \path\to\site\public\index.php -switch1 param1`

Answer (score 1):

I converted my action into Rest(ful) module action, and it worked.

Reference:

http://hounddog.github.com/blog/getting-started-with-rest-and-zend-framework-2/

The command set through Cpanel of my server:

curl http://myurl.domain